# Modificar el Copiar y Pegar de Windows

Tags: python, asp.net

Actualmente un compañero de trabajo tiene una especie de malware que me dio curiosidad su funcionamiento.

Básicamente el copia un texto en el portapapeles en windows y cuando lo pega es otro..

Esto sucede solamente cuando copia cierta cadena. en este caso es un wallet de BTC.

Copia:

```
1NiNja1bUmhSoTXozBRBEtR8LeF9TGbZBN
```

y Cuando intento pegar sale:

```
2Wallt1bUmhSoTXo4FadgtR8LeF9TGGRTR
```

Existe alguna forma de modificar el portapeles ?

Comment: Bienvenido! A que te refieres exactamente con modificar? Modificar la cadena copiada por el usuario?

Comment: si existe, lo he usado en JavaScript, puedes especificar que dato quiere que aparezca para pegar, claro, por lo que veo, tu amigo debe de usar una expresión regular para validar si lo que copio es una dirección de una cartera bitcoin.

Comment: Claro que se puede modificar. Yo usualmente lo hago usando `win32yank`, y uso pipes para meter y sacar datos.

Answer (score 0):

En *Python* puedes utilizar el *módulo pyperclip*: `pip install pyperclip`

Por ejemplo, el siguiente *script* hace que cualquier texto copiado al portapapeles se convierta en su versión *uppercase*:

```py
import pyperclip

last_copied = None

while True:

    copied = pyperclip.determine_clipboard()[1]()

    if copied != last_copied:

        copied_upper = copied.upper()
        pyperclip.copy(copied_upper)
        last_copied = copied_upper
```

El caso que expones en la pregunta puede implementarse así:

```py
import pyperclip

while True:

    copied = pyperclip.determine_clipboard()[1]()

    if copied == '1NiNja1bUmhSoTXozBRBEtR8LeF9TGbZBN':

        pyperclip.copy('2Wallt1bUmhSoTXo4FadgtR8LeF9TGGRTR')
```

El método `pyperclip.determine_clipboard` devuelve una *tupla de dos funciones*. La segunda función de esta *tupla* devuelve el *texto copiado actualmente en el portapapeles*: `copied = pyperclip.determine_clipboard()[1]()`

- Para copiar explícitamente al portapapeles utiliza `pyperclip.copy('foo')`.
- Para pegar explícitamente desde el portapapeles utiliza `pyperclip.paste()`.

Un saludo!